# have local numpy override global

Tags: python, numpy, centos

I'm using a server where I don't have administrative rights and I need to use the latest version of numpy. The system administrator insists that he cannot update the global numpy to the latest version, so I have to install it locally.

I can do that without trouble, but how do I make sure that "import numpy" results in the newer local install to be imported, as opposed to the older global version? I can adjust my PYTHONPATH, but I will want to use some of the global imports as well so I can't exclude all the global packages.

I'm on CentOS 6, by the way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python searches the path *in order,* so simply put the directory where you installed your NumPy first in the path.

You can check `numpy.version.version` to make sure you're getting the version you want.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution to this is to install and use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), which exists for exactly this reason.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good solution! I don't need something this elaborate though, and kindall's answer is a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using virtualenv, you can use `PYTHONPATH` or modify `sys.path`.

`PYTHONPATH` can be put in your `~/.bash_profile` (or whatever is an appropriate start-up file for the shell you use). Or, in `python` wrapper script which is in your `PATH` before system's `python`, e.g.:

```
$ cat ~/bin/python # assuming ~/bin is in PATH before /usr/bin
#!/bin/bash
PYTHONPATH=<path-to-your-libs> /usr/bin/python
```

Or, one may like to be explicit and command Python to use custom libraries only when asked for it. In this case `sys.path` variable can be modified directly, like:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.expanduser("~/my_python_libs"))
import numpy # searches for numpy first in "~/my_python_libs"
```

It may be handy to put the above piece of code that modifies python module search paths into a reusable module and import that module, so that when changing paths only this module needs to be modified.

For more information see [6.1.2. The Module Search Path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

Personally, I compile latest Python from the source along with all the 3rd-party libraries I use. This makes it easy to switch to the latest libraries and not depend on your Linux distribution (Linux distributions, especially enterprise ones, can't possibly keep up with Python library updates).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to use the `--user` option when you build and install numpy

```
$ python setup.py install --user
```

or

```
$ pip install --user numpy
```

This doesn't require administrative rights and there's no need to tamper with your `sys.path`

`virtualenv` is also really useful, but not necessary unless you'd like to use different versions of numpy for different applications.